# Meta functions for sequences of exponents of 2

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, variadic

I have implemented some meta functions to create sequence for exponents of 2. I would love to know if there is any way to make the code more optimized.

Note: `int main()` should not be modified. From the requirements of my school:

> This program must implement three definitions: `sequence<Ts...>`, `print()` and `printing_type()`.

Hence, the name of functions should not be modified.

```
#include<iostream>

template<size_t... Ts>
struct int_seq{}; 

template<size_t TCount, size_t...Ts>
struct sequence
{
    using type = typename sequence<TCount - 1,  1, (2 * Ts)...>::type;
};

template<size_t...Ts>
struct sequence<0, Ts...>
{
    using type = int_seq<Ts...>;
};

template<size_t TCount>
using create_int_seq  = typename sequence<TCount + 1>::type;

template <typename T>
void print(T val)
{
    std::cout << val << " ";
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(T val, Ts... t)
{
    std::cout << val << " ";
    print(t...);
}

template <
    template <size_t...> class T,
    size_t... S
>
void printing_type(T<S...>)
{
    print(S...);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t N = 63;
    create_int_seq<N> dum{};
    printing_type(dum);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly your definitions of `printing_type` and `print` could be shortened. You're currently doing

```
print(t...)  // print(a,b,c,d)
```

but what you actually want to happen is

```
print(t)...  // print(a), print(b), print(c), print(d)
```

So then you have to do a bunch of extra work to transform the former into the latter. Instead of all that extra work, you could just write

```
void print(size_t val) {
    std::cout << val << " ";
}

template<template<size_t...> class T, size_t... S>
void printing_type(T<S...>) {
    (print(S) , ...);
}
```

Notice that the single-argument `print` doesn't have to be a template, because `val` is always a `size_t`.

In fact, we can inline `print` into `printing_type` if we want:

```
template<template<size_t...> class TT, size_t... Values>
void printing_type(TT<Values...>) {
    ((std::cout << Values << " ") , ...);
}
```

The `(ts , ...)` syntax is a C++17 fold-expression. If you aren't on C++17, then you can use an initializer list to accomplish the same thing:

```
template<template<size_t...> class TT, size_t... Values>
void printing_type(TT<Values...>) {
    int dummy[] = {
        ((std::cout << Values << " "), 0) ...
    };
}
```

---

Your definition for `sequence` is pretty confusing. Your code could benefit from some *unit tests*. Compile-time unit tests are easy:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<create_int_seq<0>, int_seq<1>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<create_int_seq<1>, int_seq<1,2>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<create_int_seq<2>, int_seq<1,2,4>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<create_int_seq<3>, int_seq<1,2,4,8>>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<create_int_seq<4>, int_seq<1,2,4,8,16>>::value, "");
```

As a bonus, these five lines serve as excellent documentation about what this code does... to the extent that I no longer mind the lack of code comments explaining *how* it might work.

FWIW, if I wanted to make these test cases pass, I'd implement `create_int_seq` like this:

```
template<class> struct powers_of_two;
template<size_t... Is>
struct powers_of_two<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    using type = int_seq<(size_t(1) << Is)...>;
};

template<size_t N>
using create_int_seq =
    typename powers_of_two<std::make_index_sequence<N+1>>::type;
```

Relevant blog post of mine: ["Template metaprogramming: Iteration is better than recursion"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/23/metafilter/) (July 2018).

Comment: Man, you blow me away with those changes! Thank you so so much. Still trying to take it in. And yes, I am using c++14 currently for this.

Comment: Hi @Quuxplusone, I need to retain both print() and printing_type meta functions, and since I am using c++14, is there another optimize way instead of using the initializer list method as you have mentioned for c++14, such that I am able to use both print() and printing_type functions at the same time. And, FYI, the compiler has issued a warning being treated as error that the "dummy" variable isn't used. Hope to hear more from you. Thank you.

Comment: Re unused variable `dummy`: Add `(void)dummy;` in the body of that function.
Re needing to keep some function named `print`: Add `void print() {}` :)